# Making a header box responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, header, title

I've used the below code to add a box around a header title, however is there any way to make this responsive to fit the header text? At the moment all boxes are the size set and when scaled down to mobile go off screen, thanks for any help in advance

```
.box.active .header-title p {
    width: 600px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 0px solid white;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.4);
    opacity: 1;
  color: white
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just put border around the text? No need bind text with fixed height and width. This will not make text responsive. 
Try this code.

```
.box.active .header-title p {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Remove extra css.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 600px;
```

Is causing problems for you. This is fixed with of 600px and mobile screen is, lets say, 375px